# В хроме не удаётся отловить нажатие клавиши Ctrl

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

В Chrome код на jquery не работает, а в Firefox работает. Что может быть за магия?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {  
    if (e.ctrlKey) {    
        alert('work');
    });  
});
```

OC Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо у объекта события (event object) отсутствует ctrlKey (в Chrome). Попробуйте e.keyCode. Там можно с помощью сравнения выловить нужную клавишу. У ctrl код 17, судя по таблице вот [здесь](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: Замена if (e.ctrlKey) на if (e.keyCode == 17) помогла!
Спасибо за помощь.